# How to setup $emit in directive in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use $emit in my code for a directive.

I have

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('testDirective', testDirective);

    function testDirective() {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: testCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }

    function testCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        // do something
        vm.$emit('someEvent', {'id': '123'})
    }
})();
```

However, I am getting '`TypeError: vm.$emit is not a function`'. I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`controllerAs` just means that scoped variables are attached directly to the controller -- it doesn't mean that the controller is an instance of an angular scope itself.  In this case, you'll need to inject the scope into the controller and then emit the event from on the scope:

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    // do something
    $scope.$emit('someEvent', {'id': '123'})
}
```

Also beware, the normal injection rules apply -- If you're going to minify this, you'll probably need something like:

```
testCtrl['$inject'] = ['$scope'];
```